# Lie derivative: moving boat on a flowing river

Tags: differential-geometry, tensor-calculus, differentiation, vector-fields

Lie derivatives signifies how much a vector (Tensor) changes if flown in the direction of some other vector. I am thinking the typical moving boat on a flowing river problem where the river is flowing in the X direction with constant speed and the boat is moving in the Y direction with constant speed. After some time the velocity of the boat would be the vector sum of the boat's velocity and the flow velcocity. If I calulate the Lie Derivative in this scenario using $L_\xi V^\alpha= \xi^\mu V^\alpha,_\mu  - V^\mu \xi^\alpha,_\mu$ its zero. I struggle to find the loophole in this argument. Please help!

Comment: [review](https://www.math.brown.edu/cdaly2/Notes/Lie_Derivative.pdf).

Comment: Thanks for sharing the notes. so my X (flow of water) is say $u_0\frac{\partial }{\partial x}$ and the velocity is $Y=v_0\frac{\partial }{\partial y}$ (although its not a field so to say, should that prevent me to calculate something like the Lie derivative?) . so i get the flow of X as $\theta(t) = (y_0,  -u_0t)$ giving me the Lie derivativeas $-u_0$. Which make sense. Am I thinking right?

Comment: Compute their commutator!  It vanishes by inspection. Loophole? why should there be one?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not quite sure what you mean here, but it looked initially like maybe you were taking
$$
V = V_x \hat x + V_y \hat y,\\
\xi = x_0 \hat x + y_0 \hat y,
$$
with none of $V_x, V_y, x_0, y_0$ dependent on *t*, where *V* is the total velocity (constant) and *ξ* is the direction the Lie derivative is taken;

then, because vectors are parallel-transported in flat spacetime, the Lie derivative pushes them forward and pulls them back to the original vector. So the difference between them is zero. So the Lie derivative of a constant vector in a constant direction in flat spacetime is zero.

Comment: A river flows with velocity $u_0 \hat{x} $ and a boat moves with velocity $v_0 \hat{y}$. The Lie Derivative of $v_0 \hat{y}$ along $u_0 \hat{x}$ is zero. So that says the velocity of the boat doesn't change when it goes with the flow of the river. But then from simple vector analysis the resultant boat velocity (respect to a shore observer) becomes $V = u_0 \hat{x} + v_0 \hat{y} $, which says the boat velocity indeed changes. I wanted to reconcile this two ideas.